# Exception Design Pattern for more descriptive exceptions

Tags: python

What is a good way to add extra information to a Python exception

For example
I have nested dictionaries as so

```
d = {'Bob':{'lastname':'Smith'}, 'Sally':{}}
```

if I access the dictionary like this I get what I want which is the last name

```
name = 'Bob'
value = 'lastname'
print(d[name][value])
```

> Smith

If I try accessing Sally's last name I also get what I want which is an KeyError

```
name = 'Sally'
value = 'lastname'
print(d[name][value])
```

> KeyError: 'lastname'

However my issue is that this exception is extremely undescriptive so my code now looks like this

```
try:
   name = 'Sally'
   value = 'lastname'
   print(d[name][value])
except KeyError:
   raise KeyError("{0} has no {1}".format(name, value))
```

> KeyError: Sally has no lastname

This is gives me the descriptive error I'm looking for but I'm left wondering if this implementation is pythonic. Is there a better way to express this? I have tried looking through the python documentation and other common packages but found nothing conclusive that at least I could see

Comment: Using `'Billy'` in your second exaple will raise `KeyError: 'Billy has no lastname'` even though `'Billy'` does not exist.

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't consider that. Much appreciated that you pointed that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just lay it out there and see where that takes us. But first, look into Jeff Knupp's [article](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/) on this topic. It may be a review, but there are great little nuggets in there.

Consider the LBYL (look before you leap - see the article) approach:

```
if name not in d:
    raise KeyError('{0} is not in first level of dict'.format(name))

if value not in d[name]:
    raise KeyError('{0} is not in second level of {1}-dict'.format(value, name))
```

versus the EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission - again, see the article) approach:

```
try: 
    lastnames = d[name]
except KeyError:
    raise KeyError('{0} is not in the first level of dict'.format(name))

try:
    person = lastnames[value]
except KeyError:
    raise KeyError('{0} is not in the second level of {1}-dict'.format(value, name))
```

Now, consider the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). In my opinion, the former approach is both more "beautiful" and "simpler." It also strikes me as more "readable," albeit only by a thin margin for this case. On the other hand, the latter is more "explicit" in that it clearly delineates the possibility of failure and how to handle such cases. Furthermore, if you ever need to expand the activities around the error handling, the "practicality" of the EAFP  approach should not be ignored; should you need it, the power and convenience of the full `try: except: else: finally` clause is not to be underestimated. Having said this, I personally gravitate towards your `try: except:` solution.

However, it is perhaps more important to trust your gut. If you are conscientious enough to be thinking about these things even in simple cases, you will catch yourself in the truly tricky situations where you really ought to be considering an alternative or more pythonic approach.

Don't mind me. It's an opinion, after all.